# how reset change and destory binding happens in Backbone js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am an newbie to Backbone.js, can anyone explain what exactly these statements mean, particularly these arguments?

```
 this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
 this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
 this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on), the signature is:

```
object.on(event, callback, [context])
```

Object is any backbone object that emits events, in your case a model.

The first argument is the name of the event which we are listening for.

Second argument is a function to invoke when this event occurs, in your case render of a view.

Third argument is the *context* i.e the object to which `this` keyword points to when the callback is executed.

Comment: with reference to the documentation that you pointed out could you let me know this one thing also, when you say object.on(3 args) --> how is that related to  this.model.bind() though i see an alias "bind" there... in my case does that binds the above stated events to all the model fields.. correct me if im wrong.

Comment: `bind` and `on` are same, and yes it attaches event listeners to your model.